# PySpark - Generate StructType from string

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Is there a simple way to generate a schema from a structype definition from a string ?

For example I actualy do :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
customSchema = StructType([StructField("Date",StringType(),True)])
```

And i'm looking to store the schema définition in a table and load it dynamically like :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
stringShema = 'StructType([StructField("Date",StringType(),True)])'
customSchema = SomeFunctionToConvertTextToStruct(stringShema)
```

Any hint ?
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using eval?

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
stringSchema = 'StructType([StructField("Date",StringType(),True)])'
customSchema = eval(stringSchema)
```

Olivier.